# Installing Raqm (Libraqm) Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, dependencies, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to change the **direction** of **text** on an **image** using **pil** on **python3**, but I am unable to do so, because the **dependency** libraqm isn't installed. I can't find a way to install **libraqm**.

---

I tried to install it through pip, but it didnt work.

I also tried to find it, and I did but there are no instructions on how to install it on **Windows 10**; *only on Mac OS and Linux*. The link is:
https://github.com/HOST-Oman/libraqm/

---

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageTk, features


Coords = [0,0]
Text = 'Hello World'
colour = '#225643'
Font = ImageFont.truetype("Font/GentiumBasic-Regular.ttf", 40, 
                                 encoding="unic"))

direction = 'rtl' #Right to Left
Alignment= 'right'

til = Image.new("RGBA", (800, 500))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(til)
draw.text(Coords, Text, colour, font=Fonts, 
                  align=Alignment, direction=direction)
til.show()
```

Raises:

> File "C:\Users\Yousef\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py", line 185, in getmask2
>
> size, offset = self.font.getsize(text, direction, features, language)
>
> KeyError: 'setting text direction, language or font features is not
>      supported without libraqm'.

---

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageTk, features
print (features.check('raqm'))
print (Image.PILLOW_VERSION)
```

Returns:

> False
>
> 6.0.0

I'm just wondering on how I should install it? Any help would be much appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: You can also use [pre-built DLLs as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62939101).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Libraqm also has its own dependencies that need to be installed. The easiest way to install Libraqm and its dependencies is to use vcpkg [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg)

Here's a video that explains to to use vcpkg [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wRnjahwxZ8A)

Comment: If anyone does want to build libraqm themselves (without vcpkg) I would recommend using cmake (https://github.com/HOST-Oman/libraqm-cmake)

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to not actually install libraqm, but to get it working in python / PIL is:

- Download the unofficial build dlls from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) (search for "libraqm")
- Copy them to the same directory as your `python.exe`

Restart you kernel and it should work.