# Pillow not detecting the libraqm DLL file

Tags: python, windows-10, python-imaging-library

I am having issues with Pillow's text rendering features. I wanted to enable kerning for the font so that it looked nicer, but have descended into an endless rabbit hole of insanity.

When trying to run this code line:

```py
draw.text((1255, 224), desc, font=font.font_variant(size=94), fill=0xff0000ff, features=['kern'])
```

I receive the following error message:

```
    size, offset = self.font.getsize(
KeyError: 'setting text direction, language or font features is not supported without libraqm'
```

I've searched online for a long while and have found a few answers that have not yielded any results...
Most notably [How to install pre-built Pillow wheel with libraqm DLLs on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62939101/how-to-install-pre-built-pillow-wheel-with-libraqm-dlls-on-windows) and  [Installing Raqm (Libraqm) Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57545244/installing-raqm-libraqm-windows-10).

I was so stressed that I eventually copied and pasted the DLL files in every folder I could think of (such as System32, SysWOW64, Python38, Python38\Scripts, Python38\DLLs, etc.), but still failed.

I was even changing `PATH`, `PYTHONPATH`, and `sys.path`.

```py
>>> from PIL import features
>>> features.check('raqm')
False
```

The check above always printed `False`

I inspected the code that checks if a feature is present and checked myself, it cannot find any DLL:

```py
>>> imported_module = __import__('PIL._imagingft', fromlist=['PIL'])
>>> vars(imported_module)
{ ..., 'HAVE_RAQM': False, 'HAVE_FRIBIDI': False, 'HAVE_HARFBUZZ': False, ... }
```

For reference, these are my versions:

- Windows 10 Pro 20H2
- Pillow 8.2.0
- Python 3.8.7

I have become very desperate for any answer... Looked online for a while and was not able to find much information, always only one or two Google results had some relevance to this issue.

Comment: Have you tried placing the `libraqm.dll` in the current working directory of your script? That worked for me a while ago, when I needed Raqm support in Pillow on Windows 10.

Comment: @HansHirse, still reports as not present...

Comment: Then kindly put together a [mre] and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67805726/edit) your question accordingly, so that people can further test.

Comment: Raqm support was accidentally disabled on Windows in the 8.2.0 and 8.3.0 releases (see [discussion starting here](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4859#issuecomment-873110296)). From Pillow 8.3.1 onwards you need to use `fribidi.dll` instead of `libfribidi.dll` as explained in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77694899/1648883

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem
I tried placing `libraqm.dll` everywhere possible
After googling for days with no hope,
At the end I installed virtualbox and continued my project on Manjaro linux.

I have windows 10 Home
Version 10.0.19042 Build 19042
Pillow 8.2.0
Python 3.9.5